# How do I make this into a self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to make this function into a self-invoking function. My code is looping through an array of zip codes from a JS file and sorting it from smallest to biggest and outputting it. I've found online that adding "())" at the end of the newZipCodeArray function, is supposed to self-invoke the function. However, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
[enter image description here][1]

// Global variable
var zipCodeArray = [];

(function newZipCodeArray(currentZipCode) {

    var valueFound = false;
    for (zipCodeIndex = 0; zipCodeIndex <= zipCodeArray.length; zipCodeIndex++) {
        if (currentZipCode === zipCodeArray[zipCodeIndex]) {
            valueFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (valueFound === false) {
        zipCodeArray.push(currentZipCode);
    }
}());

function newZipCodeArrayssignment12_3() {
    // Instantiate variables.
    var output;
    var zipCodeRecords;

    // Get the element.
    output = document.getElementById('outputDiv');

    zipCodeRecords = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();

    // Call the function to read the next record.
    while (zipCodeRecords.readNextRecord()) {
        currentZipCode = zipCodeRecords.getSampleZipCode();
        newZipCodeArray(currentZipCode);
    }

    // Sort the zip code array.
    zipCodeArray.sort();
}
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Is there an error you can share?

Comment: `(function(){})();`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils this syntax also works (function(){}())
Try this (function(){console.log(123)}())

Comment: One of your functions *already is* immediately invoked. Why can't you just do the same thing again?

Comment: And why is it that you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax involved in immediately-invoked (or self-invoked) functions doesn't allow it to be invoked from elsewhere. The [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) pattern is intended to be used when the function only needs to be invoked once.

> Note:
>
> The [grouping parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) wrapping the `function` change it from a [declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) to an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). And, as an expression, its name won't be added to the surrounding scope for other code to reference.

To invoke `newZipCodeArray` once right away and allow for it again later, you'll want to remove the parenthesis from around it and call it by name in a separate statement:

```
newZipCodeArray(); // first call

function newZipCodeArray(currentZipCode) {
    // ...
}

function newZipCodeArrayssignment12_3() {
    // ...

    while (zipCodeRecords.readNextRecord()) {
        // ...
        newZipCodeArray(currentZipCode); // additional calls
    }

    // ...
}
```